# Unable to open text file in Perl

Tags: perl, file-io

I am fetching some log files (which are in txt format) from another server and trying to parse them using my Perl script. The logs are being fetched correctly after which I set permissions to 777 for the log directory.

After this I attempt to open the log files, one by one for parsing, via my Perl script. Now, the strange thing and the *problem* which happens is, my script is sometimes able to open the file and sometimes NOT. To put it simply, it's unable to open the log files for parsing at times.

Also, I have cronned this perl script and the chances of file open failing are greater when it runs via cron rather than manually, although they have run successfully in both cases previously. I don't understand where the issue lies.

Here is the code which I use for opening the files,

```
$inputDir = "/path/to/dir";
@inputFiles = <$inputDir/*>;

# inputFiles array is list of files in the log directory
foreach my $logFile(@inputFiles)
{
    # just to ensure file name is text
    $logFile = $logFile."";

    # process file only if filename contains "NOK"
    if(index($logFile,"NOK") > -1)
    {
        # opens the file
        open($ifile, '<', $logFile) or die "Error: Unable to open file for processing.";

        # file parsing takes place
    }
}

close($ifile);
```

I want to re-iterate that this code HAS run successfully and I haven't changed any part of it. Yet, it does not run every time without fail, because its unable to open the log file at times. Any ideas?

Comment: In the open line's || die put $! In the string eg open(fh,<,file) || die "error opening file $!" This will add the os's error string into perls output and give a better idea of what's going on

Comment: You add an empty string to `$logFile` "just to ensure file name is text".  What do you think it could be that is not text?

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'll try it out, and as for the "", I concatenated "" at the end because the file name was not being read correctly without it.

Comment: Rather than using `index` it would be clearer to use a regular expression: `if ($logFile =~ /NOK/) { ... }`

Comment: Have you completely omitted all ownership and file permission issues?

Comment: @Kenosis There are no ownership/permission issue since the files are created/processed by the same user. Plus, I chmod the target directory recursively to 777 before processing any file to ensure no hiccups. I believe, that if there were indeed any such issues, the script would never have run in the first place?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Maybe opening some files fails, because your program has too many open files. Your program opens *all* files in `$inputDir` and processes them in the loop. After that it closes the last file opened.

**EDIT**: after reading TLP's comment and reading `perldoc -f close` and `perldoc -f open` I see that TLP is right and the filehandle in `$ifile` is closed by a subsequent `open($ifile,'<',$logFile)` . However, if the file parsing code not shown by the topic creator creates another reference to `$ifile` the file handle would stay open.

Moving the call to `close` into the `if` block should solve your problem:

```
$inputDir = "/path/to/dir";
@inputFiles = <$inputDir/*>;

# inputFiles array is list of files in the log directory
foreach my $logFile(@inputFiles)
{

    # process file only if filename contains "NOK"
    if(index($logFile,"NOK") > -1)
    {
        # opens the file
        # added my to $ifile to keep local to this scope
        open(my $ifile, '<', $logFile) or die "Error: Unable to open file for processing.";

        # file parsing takes place

        # close current file
        close($ifile);
    }
}
```

Comment: You are probably right, I have implemented this change also in my code.

Comment: No, performing a new `open` on an old file handle closes the old one first. Though it is not a bad idea to use a lexically scoped file handle, because it automatically closes when it goes out of scope (outside the if-block).

Comment: @TLP My script has run as desired in 30+ test runs after implementing this change. Are you sure this really has no effect on script performance?

Comment: @JTG Yes. Though the change itself is a good idea, I doubt very much that this is the cause of your problem. Perhaps you have some kind of lock on the files?

Comment: @TLP I doubt if they have any lock... the log files are fetched from another server and full permissions are in place. Though, I would like to know if there is a good way to check that... "lsof" maybe?

Comment: @JTG Well, I don't know, the only way to find out is to replicate the problem, and then you have perl's errors to tell you what went wrong. One other possibility could be if you have other files being written to that directory by some other process, with other permissions.

Comment: @Dario Re: Your edit. Creating a reference to the file handle to accidentally circumvent closing it is a nice idea, however it cannot work, because `$ifile` is a global variable. So any reference to `$ifile` would be overwritten when `$ifile` is reused. If it had been a lexical variable, it would be possible.

Answer (score 5):

You should include the error message `$!` and the file name `$logFile` in your `die` string to see *why* the open failed, and for which file.

```
open($ifile, '<', $logFile) or die "Error: Unable to open $logFile: $!";
```

Also, this line:

```
$logFile = $logFile."";
```

...is quite redundant. If a conversion is necessary, perl will handle it.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'll add $! and look out for the exact failure code. Also, I concatenated "" at the end because the file name was not being read correctly without it (another mystery).

Comment: @JTG What makes you think the file name was not being read correctly? Nothing in this code could have created a corrupted file name.

Comment: To be specific, the condition which checks for "NOK" returned false for all cases, even when there was an "NOK" file. Guess it requires another post here.

Comment: @JTG Create a minimal sample script which demonstrates your problem. I'm sure its something rather simple. Nothing in this code could cause it, except by changing the input.

Comment: @JTG: Just to back up TLP: appending a null string to the file name *cannot* make any difference to this code. It is your imagination that it fixes something.

Comment: I agree with all your points, but this is not the issue for which I created this post. The issue is, why the file is not opened every time without fail because this directly affects the reliability of my script.

Comment: @JTG It may be related to your main problem. There seems to be a lot of mysterious things happening with your script.

Comment: @TLP Haha, I agree - this is one of the 2 mysteries in my script. Do you think both could be the result of the environment they are running in? Its a linux server...

Comment: @JTG It is hard to say. The best thing to do right now is wait for the problem to reappear, and then check the errors for more information.

Comment: @TLP So far its been working fine. I'll keep it under testing for at least a week longer before I can say that it is fit for use. I actually want the problem to reappear so we get to know the actual issue/solution :P

Comment: @JTG Yes, sometimes it is almost disappointing when you never find out. :P On the other hand, you should select an answer to this question and mark it as accepted.

Comment: @TLP Done - I have marked the answer which has worked for me till now.

Comment: @JTG Ugh. Have you removed this code and seen the problem reappear? I do not believe that it actually did anything and this is just a coincidence.

Comment: @TLP In fact, I did test after reverting to my original version and it failed after about half a dozen attempts, which was the basis on which I marked the answer.

Comment: @JTG And what were the error messages that you received from your `die` statements?

Comment: @TLP Damn, I forgot to include $! in the original version before testing... I'll chk it again after changing and look for the exact error.

Comment: @JTG I am waiting in suspense. :)

Comment: @TLP I was just going through my code again and realized what could be the REAL problem. The explanation is kinda big, not sure where to post it?...

Comment: @JTG Well, that depends, I guess. If its another question, post it on SO. If its an answer to your question (this question) then post it as an answer here. Why not just summarize it?

Comment: @TLP Well, to cut it really short - the inputFiles array is the prime suspect. It was loaded with filenames in the input directory. Then, I did some changes in that directory (delete/create some files), I haven't posted that code in my question , which I apologize profusely for, and then attempted to read file names from it in my for loop without updating it... This is the true reason I think.

Comment: @JTG I think I guessed that in a comment here somewhere, that files were being added/removed during runtime... although I did not suspect that it was your own script that did it. ;) Unless you need a list of the files for something else, I think it is always best to not create a separate array, but use it directly in the loop: `for my $file (grep /NOK/, <$inputdir/*>)`

Comment: @TLP. Ahh, thanks for that piece of code, half my scripts will now be modified ... I guess we can now consider this case as closed =)

Answer (score 0):

Just as an example, this is what you code should look like. You may like to try this version

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $inputDir = '/path/to/dir';
my @inputFiles = <$inputDir/*>;

foreach my $logFile (grep /NOK/, @inputFiles) {
  open my $ifile, '<', $logFile or die qq(Unable to open "$logFile": $!);
  # Process data from <$ifile>;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this tip, I'll use this in my current and upcoming projects :)